# Extend validity time of APACHE certificate

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl, certificates

I have in /etc/httpd/ssl subdir two files: apache.crt and apache.key.
How can I extend time of validity of APACHE http server, without creating new certificate and without necessity of interaction from client site?
It is important for me because current cert is valid only 30 days and I want to extend to 1 year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

The validity time is encoded into the certificate. The only way to extend it is to contact the issuer of the certificate and get a new one.

If you don't want to replace the **key**, you can sign the new request with the same key as the old one. But you still need to replace the actual `apache.crt` with the new one.

Comment: But it is self signed cert, generated during ordinary installation of Apache from ready RPM. So what can I do now to generate new one apache.crt with 1 year validity?

Comment: You generate a new self-signed cert in the same way that you generated the previous one.